# Trying to append recursively, what am I doing wrong in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

Trying to recursively append every element from list a to list c. Currently only one elements gets appended. What am I doing wrong? I', trying to reverse a list. But currently stuck understanding how to even append a list to another list.

```
(define a '(1 2 3))
(define c '())

(define fun
    (lambda (() l1) l1
            (l l1) (append l1 (car l)) (fun (cdr l) l1)
))

(fun a c)
```

I'm using a scheme like interpreter, where I cannot use any new built-in functions except of the listfunctions.

Comment: Check out Scheme syntax and compare with your Lambda form.

Comment: This Scheme-like language is not widely known. It seems to be specific to whatever course you're taking.

Comment: I think that, for people to have any hope of answering your question, you need to refer to the implementation you're using which is fairly far from standard Scheme.  In particular providing a pointer to a documented implementation would be a good start.

Comment: Unless your language is such that `append` is destructive (it normally isn't), the result of your function is just `(fun (cdr l) l1)`, and you need to use `(append l1 (car l))` for something if you want it to be part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
(lambda (l l1)
 (if (null? l)
     l1
     (append l1 (car l)) (fun (cdr l) l1)))
```

what you wrote looks like it would work if there was a pattern matching facility, but our lambda is more basic and doesn't pattern match.